# ¿Las funciones siempre retornan algo en Python?

Tags: python

Estaba desarrollando un ejercicio en Python y me di cuenta de que lo que implementé funcionó, pero no sé el por qué completamente.

```
import random


def run():

    list_one = []
    list_two = []

    random_list(8, 10, list_one)
    random_list(8, 10, list_two)
    common_numbers(list_one, list_two)


def random_list(min_length, max_length, new_list):

    for i in range(random.randint(min_length, max_length)):
        new_list.append(random.randint(1, 101))
```

Lo que hice, fue generar 2 listas de forma aleatoria con una función `random_list` y no sé claramente por qué funcionó si no tengo un return en mi función, al hacer debug, en efecto las listas vacías que declare al inicio cuando termina la ejecución de la función `random_list`, se llenan con valores aleatorios como las necesitaba y está bien.  ¿Alguien podría explicarme, por favor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondiendo a la pregunta que pusiste en el título: sí, las funciones siempre retornan algo aún cuando no pongas un `return` explícito. En ese caso retornan el valor especial `None`. Pero esto no explica por qué funciona tu código.

Lo que ocurre en tu caso es que estás pasando como último  parámetro a la función una lista, y dentro de la función **modificas** los elementos de la lista (mediante `append()`). Por eso al retorno la lista que recibe el programa principal resulta modificada.

Puedes usar la web [pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20modificar%28lista%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20lista.append%281%29%0A%20%20%20%20lista.append%282%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20main%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20data%20%3D%20%5B100%5D%0A%20%20%20%20modificar%28data%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Amain%28%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) para visualizar la ejecución de un programa sencillo y entenderlo, como por ejemplo este:

```
1  def modificar(lista):
2       lista.append(1)
3       lista.append(2)
4       
5       
6   def main():
7       data = [100]
8       modificar(data)
9       
10  main()
```

Cuando la línea 7 crea una lista con el número 100, la variable `data` es una referencia que apunta al lugar de la memoria donde se halla esa lista. Cuando invocas `modificar(data)` estás pasando esa referencia. La variable `lista` dentro de la función `modificar()`, "apunta" a la misma lista a la que apuntaba `data`, como se ve en este paso de la ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de aquí, todo lo que la función haga para modificar esa lista (añadir, quitar o reasignar elementos) sucede sobre la única lista que hay, que en este momento tiene dos referencias apuntando a ella: `lista` y `data`:

Cuando la función está a punto de retornar, la situación es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque el valor retornado será `None`, la lista original ha sido modificada.

Una vez la función retorna, la referencia llamada `lista` desaparece, y sólo queda la referencia `data`, apuntando a la lista ya modificada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto que cuando `main` retorne, la referencia `data` también desaparecerá. La lista con los números 100, 1 y 2 quedará "sin referencias" y el recolector de basura de Python la borrará de la memoria.

Answer (score 1):

La mayoría de los objetos en Python son modificables, excepto unos pocos primitivos como enteros, punto flotante y cadenas, que son inmutables.

En Python los objetos se manejan por referencia, no por copia. En otras palabras, cuando creas una lista y la "copias", como

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lista2 = lista
```

no hay dos listas, sólo una. Ambos nombres, `lista` y `lista2` se refieren a una misma lista de valores. Si modificas una, modificas la otra:

```
lista[0] = 10
lista2[1] = 20
print(lista)
print(lista2)
```

produce

```
[10, 20, 3, 4]
[10, 20, 3, 4]
```

pues ambos nombres apuntan a la misma lista.

Por tanto, cuando `run()` crea una lista y se la pasa a `random_list`, le está pasando la lista original; no una copia. Si `random_list` modifica la lista, la modificación es visible para `run()`.